# Java how to call method by reflection with primitive types as arguments

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following two methods in a class:

```
public void Test(int i){
    System.out.println("1");
}
public void Test(Integer i){
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

The following line of code

```
this.getClass().getMethod("Test",Integer.class).invoke(this, 10);
```

prints `2` , how to make it print `1`?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To call a method with primitive types as parameters using reflection :

You could use
`int.class`

```
this.getClass().getMethod("Test",int.class).invoke(this, 10);
```

or `Integer.TYPE`

```
this.getClass().getMethod("Test",Integer.TYPE).invoke(this, 10);
```

same applies for other primitive types

Answer (score 15):

Strange but true:

```
this.getClass().getMethod("Test",int.class).invoke(this, 10);
```