# Exception when invoke reflection Class.getMethod

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I have below code which invokes a method using reflection. But I am getting,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

exception at Method.invoke. What is the reason?

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Method m;
        try {
            m = a.getClass().getMethod("m3",Integer.class);
            m.invoke(a);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class A {    
    public void m3(Integer x){
        System.out.println("ssss");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments

Comment: It seems you should pass actual integer instead of Integer.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`invoke(Object, Object...)`-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) takes as it's **first** parameter the object that the method should be invoked *on* (as you did correctly) and **then** as a variable-length parameter any parameters that should be passed *to* the method call.

In your case, you're forgetting about the methods `Integer`-parameter. The method you're trying to call is `A.m3()`, which doesn't exist in the class.

The correct call would be:

```
m.invoke(a, 12); // or any int/Integer as it's second parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the original [Method.invoke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method signature -

```
public Object invoke(Object obj,
            Object... args)
              throws IllegalAccessException,
                     IllegalArgumentException,
                     InvocationTargetException
```

And it has no overloaded version. So your method call - `m.invoke()` is not correct