# Java Reflection .getMethod int vs Integer

Tags: java, reflection, integer, primitive-types

I have a class `MyClass` in package `mypackage` which looks like this:

```
package mypackage;
public class MyClass{

    public static myMethod (Integer i) {
        return i + " is an Integer";
    }

    public static myMethod (int i){
        return i + " is an int"
    } 
}
```

There is also a class `Invoker`, which looks like this:

```
public class Invoker{

    public String call(String class_name, String method_name, Serializable[] parameters){
        int p_amount = parameters.length;
        Class<?> param_types = new Class[p_amount];

        // Get types of parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < p_amount; i++){
            param_types[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
        }

        // Get method with that signature
        Method m = Class.forName(class_name).getMethod(method_name, param_types); 

        // Invoke method with given parameters
        m.invoke(null, parameters); 
    } 
}
```

Here is what happens when invoking the method:

```
int number = 3;
new Invoker().call("mypackage.MyClass", "myMethod", number)//->i is an Integer
```

Is there a way to specify that I may be calling the method with `int` as an argument?

My guess is that when `int` gets passed as a `Serializable` object, it automatically gets parsed to its cousin, the real object, `Integer`, but I am not a Java expert...

**Update**
This is NOT the same question as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments), since there one invokes directly, here there is a method in between that boxes the `int` into an `Integer`. As I mentioned before, that was my thought, but wanted other's opinions and knowledge on the matter.

Comment: You're right and given your code, there's no way around it. You could create primitive specialization for `call`.

Comment: If you've got a primitive and a matching boxed value overload for the same method, that will throw up a couple of problems like this. Ideally you should just change your class so that the methods have different names. But failing that, you can go with what @Tunaki says.

Comment: Finding the method based on the type of the parameters won't work in many situations. For example, passing a string to invoke a method taking an Object as argument will not work either, because `getMethod()` expects the actual declared types of the method arguments.

Comment: @Tunaki, what do you mean with primitive specialisation? I can do an `if parameters[i].getClass().equals(Integer.class) { param_type[i] = int.class}`, but then I would never get methods with an `Integer` in their signature. Please correct me if I understand the "primitive specialisation" wrong.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I mean overloading the `call` method. You could create a second one with a signature of `public String call(String class_name, String method_name, int[] parameters)` (its use would be very limited though). Maybe you don't need `call` at all?

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for the explanation. The problem is that this is the interface given at my university and I am not allowed to modify it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE` to identify an integer primitive.

Comment: That isn't the problem here. By the time `getMethod()` is called, the parameter is already boxed into an `Integer`, there's no way for that method to know what it was originally.

Comment: @biziclop is absolutely right.

Comment: Funnily enough, this answer is the top voted and accepted answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments)...

Comment: @regina_fallangi If this doesn't answer your question you need to be clearer about what the question is. When using reflection, the way to specify that a method parameter is a primitive `int` is to use `int.class`.

Comment: There are two different questions, one is the one  when you directly invoke, in which case the answer chosen in the question linked by @Turing85 is perfect. But in this case, there is the method `call` in between, which gets an Integer or an int and always parses it in the Serializable Array as a Integer

Comment: @regina_fallangi Well there's no answer to the second one. If your `call` method accepts an `Object[]` or an `Object...`, an `int` will always get autoboxed. There is no way around that. What you could do is overload `call` so there is another version with an `int` argument. If you are not allowed to change the interface, the question has no answer.

Comment: @PaulBoddington acutally... the question does have an answer in this case: No, you cannot call the method with parameter tpye `int`. :)

Comment: @Turing85 True. I meant writing `call("mypackage.MyClass", "myMethod", 42)`, but I agree that is not the same as passing an `int`.

Comment: @Turing85, why do you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: @regina_fallangi because a) the question is more than similar and shows the only way you can go about it and b) if you are not willing or able to change your interface, the answer to your question is: No, you cannot call the method with `int` as a parameter-type.

Comment: @Turing85, if one answer has a an specific answer and the other does not, then it is a logical implication that they are not equal, and as you mentioned before, a "No possible" is also an answer. My update shows there is no possible answer w/ changing the interface.

Comment: @regina_fallangi So you got your answer and people who read this question get redirected to a very similar question with a solution.