# How to use reflection to invoke a method with primitive arguments?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to create a method `invokeMethod(String methodName, Object...args)` which invokes a method from a superclass on the current instance. I have tried the following implementation.

```
    public void invokeMethod(String methodName, Object...args) {
        //Array to hold the classes of the arguments
        Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[args.length]; 
        //Initialize each class in the array to the class of each argument 
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            classes[i] = args[i].getClass();
        try {
            //find the method
            Method m = this.getClass().getMethod(methodName, classes);
            //invoke the method
            m.invoke(this, args);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem with this implementation is if I try to invoke a method with primitive parameters, I get a `NoSuchMethodException` because it is looking for a method with parameters whose type is the wrapper class equivalent.

For example, if I try to invoke a method with signature `line(float, float, float, float)` by trying `invokeMethod("line", 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f)`, I get an exception similar to

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DynamicSketch.line(java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
at DynamicSketch.invokeMethod(DynamicSketch.java:32)
at DynamicSketch.setup(DynamicSketch.java:19)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2412)
at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

Is there anyway to make my `invokeMethod` method work with primitive arguments?

Edit: The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments) does not work because I do not know exactly what primitive types are in the signature when executing my method. I want to be able to execute methods like `size(int, int)` and `line(float, float ,float ,float)` using my method, and the solution in the link does not easily work with this. The only solution I see to this is define an if statement for every possible method in the superclass and then use the solution in the link, but I wanted a less tedious way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java how to call method by reflection with primitive types as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments)

Comment: The solution in the linked duplicate means that you will have to change the signature of your method, exactly *because* it cannot differentiate between primitive types and their wrappers.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have edited my question to address this

Comment: I somehow have the vague feeling that you might want to take a look at [getMatchingMethod](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html) in apache commons.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It seems the main benefit of `getMatchingMethod` is I don't need the `this.getClass()` part and this library has more options for invoking the method. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: I don't remember all the details. I just wanted to mention that there is an apache commons library specifically for invoking methods via reflection. There are a dozen of `invokeXyzMethod`-methods there, maybe one of them is somehow useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When arguments such as `10` or `10.0f` are passed into the method, they are automatically wrapped, because the parameter type is `Object...`.

Therefore, you need to check for these wrapper types and unwrap them. Your for loop can look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (args[i].getClass() == Integer.class) {
        classes[i] = int.class;
    } else if (args[i].getClass() == Float.class) {
        classes[i] = float.class;
    } else if (args[i].getClass() == Double.class) {
        classes[i] = double.class;
    } else {
        classes[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
}
```

I have only added 3 cases here, you can add the other 5 yourself.

This means that you can't call methods with wrapper type arguments now. If you want to call those as well, you need to

1. unwrap all the wrapper types
2. try to find a method with those non-wrapper types
3. If not found, wrap them up again
4. find the a method using the wrapper types.

Edit:

As Holger suggested in the comments, you can also let the JVM find a suitable method for you, by using

```
new Statement(this, methodName, args).execute();
```

[Docs for the `Statement` class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Statement.html)

Comment: And what if the invoked method actually expects `Float` and `Integer` instead of `float` and `int`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That's what the last part of my answer addresses. If that is the case, OP would have to check if a method with primitive arguments exist, and if not, check if a method with the wrapper type arguments exist.

Comment: That still doesn't quite solve the problem if there are multiple methods with "essentially the same signature", but differing only in the "wrappedness" of their arguments? The method signature of `invokeMethod` is just too restrictive, it doesn't allow to disambiguate all the cases.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You mean methods with mixed argument types like `foo(Integer, int)`? I don't think those are very common, and if OP needs to handle those as well, they would need to iterate through all the permutations of "wrappedness", but I doubt OP needs to handle that. Quote "I want to be able to execute methods like `size(int, int)` and `line(float, float ,float ,float)` using my method".

Comment: could be more common that one might think. E.g. `put(int idx, Integer value)` on `ArrayList<Integer>` comes to mind. Would it handle it properly? I don't know, that's why I proposed to take a look at apache commons reflection utils.

Comment: @Sweeper Fortunately, none of the methods seems to have a wrapper class parameter, so I like that you included the algorithm at the end. Out of curiosity, is there a non-awkward way to handle the case where there are two methods where one is with primitive parameters `m(int, int)` and one with wrapper class parameters `m(Integer, Integer)`?

Comment: @Lindstorm You could add a boolean parameter to `invokeMethod` called `preferWrapper`. If that is true, look for a method with wrapper parameters first. If not, look for a method with primitive parameters first.

Comment: Or just use [`new Statement(this, methodName, args).execute();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Statement.html)…

Comment: @Holger Wow! Thanks, edited. Never knew such a method existed. Technically `Statement` is in the `java.beans` package, so does it really count as reflection? I dunno.

Comment: Well the `java.beans` package is a library settling atop the Reflection facility. I’d still count it as Reflection but with higher-level convenience features.