# How do I convert the string to the setter function, if the method takes a primitive type?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to generate a setter for a class which takes a parameter of primitive type, but I am getting an exception since only non-primitives are allowed.

For this I am taking a string and converting it exactly the way the function is in my POJO, but while describing the type of the parameter (int) it's taking its wrapper class (Integer).

```
Method method = resultClass.getClass().getMethod(getSetMethod(key), value.getClass());


private String getSetMethod(String key) {
    key = key.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + key.substring(1);
    key = "set"+key;
    return key;
}
```

Can anyone tell me if there is an alternative way to generate this method which works for both the primitive and non-primitive types?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411426/java-how-to-call-method-by-reflection-with-primitive-types-as-arguments as far as I understand the question, this can help you. You can use `int.class` for setter of primitive `int` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to add libraries. The library [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) can be used to handle beans and properties.

In your case you could do:

```
Method method = PropertyUtils.getReadMethod( new PropertyDescriptor(key, resultClass));
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained the purpose of this, but if I understand you correctly, `value` is an example value for a property, and you want to use it to find out the parameter type of the setter method.

But `value.getClass()` is really not suitable for this, because:

1. It can't return a primitive type.
2. It might return a subclass of the setter method's parameter type.
3. It will throw an NPE if `value` is null.

So some possible alternatives:

1. Supply the setter as a lambda function, instead of trying to hack into things with reflection. This is more performant and more flexible than using reflection.
2. If you must use reflection, supply an extra `Class` variable to your code so it knows the correct parameter type of the setter method.
3. Or, go wild, and grab the first method you see which has the setter name, no matter its type:

   ```
   Method method;
   String name = getSetMethod(key);
   for (Method m : resultClass.getClass().getMethods()) {
       if (m.getName().equals(name)) {
           method = m;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me if there is an alternative way to generate this method which works for both the primitive and non-primitive types?

You can't do that. You can't have **one** method object that works for `foo(int)` and `foo(Integer)`. Because those would be two different methods.

The reason why the compiler allows you to call some `foo(Integer)` with `foo(5)` is because the compiler uses boxing to turn 5 into an Integer object, to then pass that.

Remember: the compiler decides at compile time which method will be invoked. When there are two methods of the same name with different argument types, then that is **overloading** ... and happens at compile time.

Long story short: either you have to create **two** Method objects, or **you** have to provide the necessary code to box/unbox between primitive and boxed reference types as needed!

Answer (score 0):

You will need some special handling to match these methods with primitive parameters with the corresponding boxed types.

A simple approach that might suffice is to create a mapping between the boxed and primitive types, and look for methods using both types. This is just a sketch:

```
    Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> boxedToPrimitive = new HashMap<>();
    boxedToPrimitive.put(Integer.class, Integer.TYPE);
    boxedToPrimitive.put(Long.class, Long.TYPE);
    boxedToPrimitive.put(Boolean.class, Boolean.TYPE);
    ...

    String name = getSetMethod(key);
    Method method;
    try {
        method = target.getClass().getMethod(name, val.getClass());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException missing) {
        Class<?> alt = boxedToPrimitive.get(val.getClass());
        if (alt == null) throw missing;
        method = target.getClass().getMethod(name, alt);
    }
    method.invoke(target, value);
```